# Latex Multirow Table formatting

Tags: tables

I am trying to format a table using `multirow` and `multicolumn`. Most of it seems ok except that I am missing some borders and I would a line separator between row "Binary Classifier" and the row immediately beneath it (1 vs. 2) etc. I cannot seem to figure it out.

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Category} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}  {Binary Classifier} &  \multirow{2}{*}{Votes}    & \multirow{2}{*}{Result}\\

           &  1 vs. 2  &  1 vs. 3   & 2 vs. 3\\
\hline Class 1 & Win & Win & X & 2 & Win \\ 
\hline Class 2 & X & X & Win & 1 & X \\ 
\hline Class 3 & X & X & X & 0 & X \\ 
\hline  
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: First, you will get quicker assistance with a compilable MWE.  Search this site for MWE for more information.   Second, change line 5 to read          ' &  1 vs. 2  &  1 vs. 3   & 2 vs. 3&  &\\ ' because in each row you must account for all specified columns (you declared there would be six)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add a `\cline` for the missing horizontal line and add the missing cells for the second row.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|*{5}{c|}}
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{Category} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Binary Classifier} & \multirow{2}{*}{Votes} & \multirow{2}{*}{Result} \\\cline{2-4} 
                & 1 vs.\ 2 & 1 vs.\ 3 & 2 vs.\ 3 &   &     \\\hline 
        Class 1 & Win      & Win      & X        & 2 & Win \\\hline 
        Class 2 & X        & X        & Win      & 1 & X   \\\hline
        Class 3 & X        & X        & X        & 0 & X   \\\hline  
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Save yourself some trouble while making it look more beautiful. Here are some general advice on printing tables.

- Don't use vertical lines, unless your table is meant to be read vertically.
- Use some different widths of horizontal lines. The `booktabs`-package has som nice predefined lengths(along with some very good advice), namely `\toprule`,`\midrule` and `\bottomrule`.
- Use a caption on top. (for figures, the caption can below it).
- Don't write `\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|}` with that many repeating items. use `\begin{tabular}{|l|*{5}{c|}}` if you reall want vertical lines, or `\begin{tabular}{l*{5}{c}}` without vertical lines. That way, you specify the number of columns you want of type c, instead of typing one by one.

**Output**

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Some binary stuff\ldots}
    \begin{tabular}{l*{5}{c}}
        \toprule
        \multirow{2}{*}{Category} & \multicolumn{3}{c}  {Binary Classifier} &  \multirow{2}{*}{Votes}    & \multirow{2}{*}{Result}\\

                   &  1 vs. 2  &  1 vs. 3   & 2 vs. 3\\
        \midrule
         Class 1 & Win & Win & X & 2 & Win \\ 
         Class 2 & X & X & Win & 1 & X \\ 
        Class 3 & X & X & X & 0 & X \\ 
        \bottomrule  
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```